# Vlookup in python

Tags: python, text-processing

I am new to python and leaning as fast as possible. I know how to do my problem in bash and trying to work on python.
I have a data file (data_array.csv in the example) and index file, index.csv, at which I want to extract the data from the data file that have the same ID in the index file and store in to a new file, Out.txt. I also want to put NA ,in the Out.txt, for those ID's that have no value in the data file. I know how to do it for one column. But my data has more than 1000 columns (from 1 to 1344). I want you help me with a script that can do it faster. My data file, index id and proposed out put as follows.

### data_array.csv

```
Id  1   2   3   .   .   1344
1   10  20  30  .   .   -1
2   20  30  40  .   .   -2
3   30  40  50  .   .   -3
4   40  50  60  .   .   -4
6   60  60  70  .   .   -5
8   80  70  80  .   .   -6
10  100 80  90  .   .   -7
```

### index.csv

```
Id
1
2
8
9
10
```

Required Output is

### Out.txt

```
Id  1   2   3   .   .   1344
1   10  20  30  .   .   -1
2   20  30  40  .   .   -2
8   80  70  80  .   .   -6
9   NA  NA  NA          NA
10  100 80  90  .   .   -7
```

I tried

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import csv

with open('data_array.csv','r') as lookuplist:
    with open('index.csv', "r") as csvinput:
        with open('VlookupOut','w') as output:

            reader = csv.reader(lookuplist)
            reader2 = csv.reader(csvinput)
            writer = csv.writer(output)

            for i in reader2:
                for xl in reader:
                    if i[0] == xl[0]:
                        i.append(xl[1:])
                        writer.writerow(i)
```

But it only do for the first row. I want the program to work for the entire rows and columns of my data files.

Answer (score 2):

It only output the first row because after `xl in reader` for the first time, you are at the end of the file. You need to point to the beginning of the file after that. To increase efficiency, you can read the `csvinput` into a dictionary first, then use dictionary lookup to get the row you need:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import csv

with open('data_array.csv','r') as lookuplist:
    with open('index.csv', "r") as csvinput:
        with open('VlookupOut','w') as output:

            reader = csv.reader(lookuplist)
            reader2 = csv.reader(csvinput)
            writer = csv.writer(output)

            d = {}
            for xl in reader2:
                d[xl[0]] = xl[1:]

            for i in reader:
                if i[0] in d:
                    i.append(d[i[0]])
                writer.writerow(i)
```

Comment: the program matches the index and data file and execute only values of the data file that are in the index. I am interested in executing all the index as in the example for further step.

Comment: @Abraham, sure. Just moved `writer.writerow(i)` to outside of the `if` statement

Answer (score 1):

When you read a CSV file using `for xl in reader`it will go through every row until it reaches the end. But it will only do this once. You can tell it to go back to the first row of the CSV file by using `.seek(0)`.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import csv

with open('data_array.csv','r') as lookuplist:
    with open('index.csv', "r") as csvinput:
        with open('VlookupOut','w') as output:

            reader = csv.reader(lookuplist)
            reader2 = csv.reader(csvinput)
            writer = csv.writer(output)

            for i in reader2:
                for xl in reader:
                    if i[0] == xl[0]:
                        i.append(xl[1:])
                        writer.writerow(i)
                lookuplist.seek(0)
```